# I need to search google using javascript , for example when I run the code it opens new tab that google's Trump for me

Tags: javascript

---code here that googles Trump automatically when it runs--

like that

```
var word ="Trump";

function googleItPlease (word) {
    $('#someIdHere').newTab('show');
}
```

Comment: pls forgive my bad coding skill that I could not put it up all together , but I need to google something using pure javascript code :)

Comment: This isn't possible in pure JavaScript, because you can't access pages on 3rd party domains due to security reasons. If this is just for your own browser at home, you can look into a browser automation framework like Greasemonkey

Answer (score 2):

There is a google api you can use.
I recommand using rest + ajax call to accomplish this.

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest

for example:

```js
var key = "12345"; // your api key registered with google.

$.ajax({
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key="+key+"q="+query
}).then(
  function(data){
    // read data from here...
  }
)
```